# FullCalendar set date background color from date in sql database

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am using JQUERY FullCalendar plugin to build an app in .net MVC C#.
What I am trying to achieve is to set background color of certain days fetched from a sql database when the calendar loads (not on an eventclick), or the previous and next buttons are clicked.

Does anyone know how to make an `$.ajax` call to retrieve db dates inside the FullCalender plugin? Or a better implementation for what I'm trying to achieve? I know how to implement a $.ajax call to return Json data, it just wont work inside the dayRender event......

See Below Code:

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetOrderDates()
{
    List<string> dates = new List<string>();

    var days = db.Orders.Where(d => d.OrderDate != null).Select(d => d.OrderDate).Distinct().ToArray();

    foreach (var item in days)
    {
        dates.Add(item.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
    }


    return Json(dates, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Script:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header: {
        left: 'prev, next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month'
    },

    dayRender: function (date, cell) {

        var date = new Date(date);
        var day = date.getDate().toString();

        if (day.length == 1) //FIX DAY FORMAT ID 2 = 02 TO MATCH DB ARRAY
            day = 0 + day;

        var year = date.getFullYear(); //GET YEAR

        var month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
        if (month.length == 1)
            month = 0 + month;


        var dateStr = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;


       // These values will be retrieved from db.. Hard coded for simplicity. 
        var dbDates = ['2015-10-09', '2015-10-10', '2015-10-30']


        for (var i = 0; i < dbDates.length; i++) {

            if (dateStr == dbDates[i].toString()) {
                    cell.css("background-color", "lightblue");
                }

        }

    }
};
```

Ajax call... (Where do I make this call and return list of dates to dayRender:)

```
$.ajax('/Home/GetOrderDates', function(data){

});
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: can you simply trying fetching all dates and store them in a `dbDates` variable before full calendar javascript and then use that variable directly inside dayRender.

Comment: @AnantKolvankar .. I tried that approach but it didn't work...  I created a global variable to hold the dates... And also created a function that is called when the DOM is ready that populates the global variable..   But anywhere outside the function the variable becomes null...  Any suggestions?  Thank you..

Comment: You mean the global variable is set with dates properly but just before using it in dayrender global variable become null, can you past your code here